# tfjs: Error: Argument tensors passed to stack must be a `Tensor[]` or `TensorLike[]`

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

The exact same question has been posted a few times, but unfortunately haven't found the answer. What I'm trying to do is to build a one-to-one RNN, where the previous timestep's output is the input of the current timestep with the layers API. Here's my example code, tried to make it as simple as possible:

```js
const cells = [
  tf.layers.simpleRNNCell({units: 4, activation: 'relu'}),
  tf.layers.simpleRNNCell({units: 3, activation: 'relu'}),
];
const rnn = tf.layers.rnn({cell: cells, returnSequences: true});


const x = tf.tensor([
 [
   [10, 8, 5],
 ],
 [
   [0, 2, 0],
 ],
]);

const y = tf.tensor([
  [
    [0.3, 0.5, 0.4],
  ],
  [
    [0.1, 0, 0]
  ]
])

const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.inputLayer({ inputShape: [1, 3] }))
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 model.add(rnn)
};

model.compile({
 loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
 optimizer: 'adam',
 metrics: ['accuracy']
});

model.fit(x, y, {
 epochs: 10,
 batchSize: x.shape[0],
 yieldEvery: 'batch'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
```

You can try it as well, it will throw an error (in browser it throws: `Error: 'slice' not yet implemented or not found in the registry. This kernel may not be supported by the tfjs backend you have chosen`, in node it throws what's in the question title).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, did you solve the problem? I got same error here.